# How to write a batch for weinre and keep it open?

Tags: batch-file, weinre

I wrote a batch file and key in as follow:

```
weinre --httpPort 8181 --boundHost 192.168.1.110
```

I supposed it will start up a cmd and run only once, then show the message as follow and wait:

```
2013-06-05T10:50:40.636Z weinre: starting server at http://192.168.1.51:8181
_
```

But in fact it just kept running without stop.

this is my first time trying to write a batch file, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@echo off
start "" weinre --httpPort 8181 --boundHost 192.168.1.110
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it don't work for me. It will keep startup a new window and shut itself down immediately.

Comment: You may not be aware that opening a new window and closing it is normal - the server should still be running though.

Comment: Your batch is totally not working at all. It just repeatedly open new command window and shutdown itself. The weinre is not running by your batch and PC become unusable by endless new command window. The only way to escape is to log off or restart PC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you called the batch file `weinre` so it was starting itself again and again.